# ProductScreen.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

im running into a problem and no matter how much research/googling i do, i cant seem to fix this issue, been dealing with this error for last 2 days, first i tried to find any answer online someone else might have had but i cant seem to figure it out, so now i need to ask someone more experienced as to what im doing wrong, please take a look at my error and code pictures and see if you might catch something i cant... tunnel vision..

frontend is reactjs and backend is node/express

when i open up home screen page, every product loads from the backend, no issue, but once i click onto single product to try and get that specific product page with unique id, initial skeleton loads for a brief moment without having any of the products information, before crashing with following error

"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')"

now i have tried different solutions and ways to go around that, checked if the issue might with react-router-dom(useParams), backend server/api(get request and find single product) or the frontend side of fetching single product via axios, but since im doing the same thing on HomeScreen page while fetching all products with axios, i cant figure out why it might not work with single product, im using useState and useEffect to fetch single product from the backend api.

here is single product screen, the fetch part of it at least

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import axios from 'axios'

const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
const [product, setProduct] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
        setProduct(data)
    }

    fetchProduct()
}, [match])
```

server file

```
const express = require('express')
const products = require('./data/products')

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('API is running...')
})

app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
res.json(products)
})

app.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res) => {
const product = products.find((p) => p._id === req.params.id)
res.json(product)
})
```

app.js file

```
   import React from 'react'
   import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react- 
   router-dom'
   import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
   import Header from './components/Header'
   import Footer from './components/Footer'
   import HomeScreen from './pages/HomeScreen'
   import ProductScreen from './pages/ProductScreen'

   const App = () => {
   return (
   <Router>
   <Header />
        <main className='py-3'>
            <Container>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
                    <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductScreen />} />
                </Routes>
            </Container>
        </main>
        <Footer />
    </Router>
)
}

export default App
```

thanks in advance

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: how else is someone going to find out what might be wrong with my code?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: alright edited first post, got rid of all the images and left only the question

Comment: You're meant to include your code in the question, otherwise how can anybody offer any help

Comment: He's not saying get rid of code, he's saying put the code in as text instead of images

Comment: that is what i was doing, deleting the images and adding code, its in now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access route params within your `ProductScreen` component through props. React Router v6 does not pass props to *elements*...

```html
<Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductScreen />} />
```

From the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element)...

> Using elements instead of components means we don't have to provide a `passProps`-style API so you can get the props you need to your elements.

To access route params, use the [*params* hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams)

```js
// ...
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ProductScreen = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({})
  const { id } = useParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`)
      setProduct(data)
    }

    fetchProduct()
  }, [ id ])
```

Comment: i tried useParams solution before, but none of them had "${encodeURIComponent(id)}" part in them, i have tried your suggested solution, and now it works as intended, thank you very much

Comment: `encodeURIComponent()` is just a bit of extra safety. I doubt that's what made this work